# How to share a deep link on social networks in react native

Tags: javascript, java, android, facebook, react-native

as the title says, I'd like to know if there's a way to share URL deep link in a social network (eg: twitter, facebook, whatsaap, etc). I'm using this library [react-native-share](https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share) but since it isn't a web URL but a URL from an App (The URL is something like: myapp://app/1 (the last part is the parameter that I have to send)) the message doesn't appear as a hyperlink but just as a simple string, like a normal message in the social network. I tried making the text a link with the .link function from javascript, but that only works on web browsers, I'd like to know if there's another way to accomplish this or if you have any idea of how to convert the message into a clickable link. I just want the others apps to recognize it as a link and let it open on the web browser, that way It'll open the app I'm developing.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem... did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this intent filter in your AndroidManifest.xml first.

```
<activity
    [...]

    <intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="http"
            android:host="www.your-domain.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/new/9/read" />
      <data android:scheme="appname"
            android:host="yourhost" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Then you can use the [Linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) API that react-native provides to handle your deep links.

ex:

```
componentDidMount() {
  Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
    if (url) {
      console.log('Initial url is: ' + url);
    }
  }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
}
```

Comment: I've already done that. The deep linking works perfectly, what I'm asking for is for a way to share that url to social networks like facebook or whatsaap since it doesn't share as a hyperlink but as a normal text, so people can't click it and enter to the specific part of the app.

Comment: could you add the explanation for how did you solved it?

Comment: @MarcoPortillo Could you share the code how did you resolve this. I am also facing the same problem. Text is not clickable in react-native-share.

Comment: @MarcoPortillo: I would also be interested in how you solved it!

Comment: @MarcoPortillo Hi, it's been a long time but do you remember how you solved this problem?

Comment: @EmmanuelGarciaMartinez Hi, I am sorry, back then I forgot to post the answer here and I do not work with this anymore, so I do not remember :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use FBSDK and use the `ShareDialog.share({contentHere})`.
[image: Facebook share]

[Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog/)